# How can I maximize the source impedance of the Arduino Due's ADC?

Tags: arduino, adc

I know that the ADC on the Arduino Due has a clock speed from 1 MHz to 20 MHz. This is given by the data sheet:
[image]

I want to lower f_ADC to maximize source impedance:
[image]

I want to slow down the ADC as much as possible is to obtain the maximum source impedance. **However, according to [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/12723/1375) post, Arduino sets the ADC clock to 125 KHz.**

**How is this possible, if the data sheet says that the minimum is 1 MHz?** Finally, if I utilize the Arduino backend C++ code to slow down the ADC, then can I extrapolate that the source impedance will reach MΩ values?)

Comment: This is going to be a bit difficult.

ADCs don't have source impedances. They have load impedances. ADCs are not sources, they are loads.

The Zsource specified in the table is the source impedance of whatever is driving the ADC. In order to allow internal capacitances to properly charge up or down after a clock edge, the faster the clock rate, the lower the source impedance needs to be. So lowering the clock rate will allow the ADC to work as advertised with a higher-impedance source. What is the impedance of your signal-conditioning circuit which is feeding your ADC?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what your intentions are with this. But the bandwidths concerned are not very high in any case. You could feasibly add a FET input opamp as a buffer to raise the effective input impedance of the ADC dramatically.

Comment: The source impedance is around 200kOhms, and it is a dc source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum recommended source impedance for this MCU is 10K ohms. This takes into account sampling time and leakage of the I/O pins. However, you could easily add an [op-amp voltage follower](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00109017.pdf) and get extremely high input resistance.

The one I linked has typical 1pA maximum 30pA leakage over temperature and reasonable 3mV offset voltage, but may others are available. That particular part would cause <0.1% error over the entire temperature range with 300M\$\Omega\$ source resistance! (Typically at room temperature 5G\$\Omega\$ for 0.1% error).

Comment: This is a Due - which is a Atmel SAM ARM processor, *not* and AVR.

Comment: True, but a voltage follower is still the way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the answer for the other question was not correct.

"The Arduino" is not a specific processor, it's a platform that uses different processors. You've found the exact source where your question is answered, the datasheet.

In section 43.6.1 it says:

> The ADC clock range is between MCK/2, if PRESCAL is 0, and MCK/512, if
>   PRESCAL is set to 255 (0xFF)

and elsewhere that MCK can be a few hundred hertz. With a max MCK of 84 MHz it seems clear that the input can be at least (84 MHz)/512 (164.0625 kHz). Why else have a 512 prescaler?

However, you can't just extrapolate the table, though a more relevant portion of the table *is* on the data sheet.

[image]

The behavior of the device below the tested values will be up to you to test, but you should consider it unreliable.